# Why does joda DateTimeZone's getOffset() method require an "instant"?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

What I'm trying to do:

From a DateTimeZone object, I'm trying to get the GMT offset in milliseconds. Example:

```
DateTimeZone gmt= // somehow get gmt zone object
long offset = gmt.getOffsetSomehow(); // expect offset = 0

DateTimeZone ny_est = // somehow get that time zone object representing "EST" offset of NY zone
long offset = ny_est.getOffsetSomehow(); // expect offset = -18000000 = -5*60*60*1000

DateTimeZone hkt = // somehow get HK time zone object
long offset = hkt.getOffsetSomehow(); // expect offset = 28800000 = 8*60*60*1000
```

Joda's DateTimeZone object has a method called [getOffset](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29), which accepts a parameter. Question:

1. why does that method need a parameter? I would have expected the method to not expect any param, and simply behave how I want my fictitious "getOffsetSomehow()" method.
2. How can I get the time zone objects in my snippet above?
3. What actual method/snippet of code can get me the "offset" values I'm try to get?

Comment: @jrharshanth If you are putting the question; and if answer is working for you; you can accept the answer.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, too.  I initialized and saved a DateTimeZone using `DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(...)` in one part of my application, and now I want to get the offset back again so that I can save the int or long value in a database.  Presumable the DateTimeZone object is storing the offset in one of its instance fields.  There's no obvious way to get at that data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is, because the Offset changes over time. One example is daylight saving time. Another is  a country deciding to move to another timezone.

If you want the current offset, just hand in now like this:

```
int offset = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin").getOffset(new DateTime());
System.out.println(offset);
```

Comment: getOffset() method is an abstract method not an static method of the DateTimeZOne class. So through object of DateTimeZone class only it can be accessed.  ex.   
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Port_of_Spain");// America/New_York,Asia/Kolkata
  DateTimeZone.setDefault(dtz);
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 3, 10, 3, 0, dtz);
  dtz.getOffset(dt.getMillis());

Comment: You're right, fixed my example. However, my answer stays the same: One has to provide an instant (aka point in time) when asking for a TZ offset, since it changes over time

Answer (score 0):

2) You can get TimeZone object by this way - `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");`

3 You can get offset Value by this method -

```
double timezoneval = 0.0;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2013, 3, 25, 10, 0,0);
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        boolean t = tz.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
        if (t)
            timezoneval = ((TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset())
                    / (60 * 60 * 1000D) + (TimeZone.getDefault()
                    .getDSTSavings() / (60 * 60 * 1000D)));
        else
            timezoneval = ((TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()) / (60 * 60 * 1000D));
```

1) I did not get your question.

This offset value will be applicable for Day light saving and non Day light saving country.

Comment: You can place any valid timezone string  id instead of "Asia/Kolkata to get timezone object. You can use Joda Time API for more ease in Date Time Calculation in Java

Comment: If you are using DateTimZone of JodaTime Api; the you have to to use DateTimeZone class static method. I had given assuming that you are using Java.util.DateTime.

Comment: @jr you can use this in JodaTime API -   
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Port_of_Spain");// America/New_York,Asia/Kolkata
  DateTimeZone.setDefault(dtz);
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 3, 10, 3, 0, dtz);
  dtz.getOffset(dt.getMillis());